# Setup for testing a Linq query on a LinqToExcel IExcelQueryFactory

Tags: c#, linq, mocking, moq, linq-to-excel

Using c#, Moq, MSTest, LinqToExcel

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to Setup() a mock for a response from a Linq query on a Linq-to-Excel IExcelQueryFactory.

I think I should expect the Linq Query to return something of type delegate, but I'm not quite sure what that should look like

Can anyone suggest what my Return() should look like in the Moq Setup() below?

Also, any toughts on my approach to testing and mocking these Lynq methods?  Should I be approaching this differently?

Thanks!  I'm going to go book up on delegates now. :)

**The Test**

```
[TestClass]
public class ThingsSheetTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetRows_ReturnsListOfThings()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockExcelQueryFactory = new Mock<IExcelQueryFactory>();
        var thingsSheet = new ThingsSheet(mockExcelQueryFactory.Object, "file", "worksheet");

        mockExcelQueryFactory
        .Setup(x => x.Worksheet<Thing>(It.IsAny<string>))

        // I think this is correctly casting to a delegate
        // however ExelQuerable constructor needs arguments:
        // public ExcelQueryable(IQueryProvider provider, Expression expression);
        // looking into what kind of IQueryProvider and Expression I should supply.

        .Returns(Action(() => new ExcelQueryable<Thing> { }));   // getting closer!


        // Act
        thingsSheet.GetRows();

        // Assert
        mockExcelQueryFactory.Verify();

    }
}
```

**The Class and Method I'm testing**

```
public class ThingsSheet
{
    private string importFile;
    private string worksheetName;
    private IExcelQueryFactory excelQueryFactory;
    public ThingsSheet(IExcelQueryFactory excelQueryFactory, string importFile, string worksheetName)
    {
        this.excelQueryFactory = excelQueryFactory;
        this.importFile = importFile;
        this.worksheetName = worksheetName;
        this.AddMappings();
    }

    private void AddMappings()
    {
        excelQueryFactory.AddMapping<Thing>(t => t.Id, "Thing ID");
    }

    public List<Thing> GetRows()
    {
        excelQueryFactory.AddMapping<Thing>(t => t.Id, "Thing ID");

        var things = from thing in excelQueryFactory.Worksheet<Thing>(this.worksheetName)
                   select new Thing { };

        return things.ToList<Thing>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use e.g. a **method** which returns your fake data.

```
mockExcelQueryFactory
    .Setup(x => x.Worksheet<Thing>(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(ExcelQueryableOfThing());
```

Lets say **Thing class** looks like this:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the method `ExcelQueryableOfThing()` you have to mock the `CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)` method of IQueryProvider provider. Something like this:

```
private ExcelQueryable<Thing> ExcelQueryableOfThing()
{
    var things = new List<Thing>
    {
        new Thing
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Adam"
        },
        new Thing
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Eva"
        }
    }
    .AsQueryable();

    Mock<IQueryProvider> queryProvider = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
    queryProvider
        .Setup(p => p.CreateQuery<Thing>(It.IsAny<Expression>()))
        .Returns(() => things);

    Expression expressionFake = Expression.Constant(new List<Thing>().AsQueryable());

    return new ExcelQueryable<Thing>(queryProvider.Object, expressionFake);
}
```

Then in the unit test `thingsSheet.GetRows()` will return your fake data (Adam and Eva :). HTH

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetRows_ReturnsListOfThings()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IExcelQueryFactory> mockExcelFile = new Mock<IExcelQueryFactory>();
    var thingsSheet = new ThingsSheet(mockExcelFile.Object, "file", "worksheet");

    mockExcelFile
        .Setup(x => x.Worksheet<Thing>(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(ExcelQueryableOfThing());

    // Act
    List<Thing> rows = thingsSheet.GetRows();

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(2, rows.Count); // Adam and Eva
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I get a "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ExcelQueryable<Thing>' because it is not a delegate type."  So I'm trying to puzzle out how I can cast that to a delegate.

Comment: updated the test in my original post.. I believe it's casting to a delegate correctly, but I think I need to give a couple arguments to ExcelQueryable()... Looking into what kind of IQueryProvier and Expression I need to supply...  have to say, this test is starting to look a lot more complicated than the code it's testing

Comment: Thanks again! It's working, and I get the general idea.  I'm going to have to take a few more looks at it before it sinks in.  Really appreciate your help.